# WPF .NET4.0 Listbox and ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

Im trying to populate a ListBox with items. The `ItemsSource` is as follows:

```
public SortedDictionary<string, List<int>> AvailableValues
```

when I have the following the items seem to be nicely layed out. Except that I cant select a whole item and perform some function on it.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableValues}">

            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <CustomControls:UniformWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Key}" />
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInputValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Ive tried replacing `ItemsControl` with `ListBox` (as well as `ListBox.ItemTemplate`) and cant seem to get a display where by the `Label` `Content` is left aligned and the `Combobox` content is right aligned.

The `UniformWrapPanel` is from the CodeProject article.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If alignment is the main issue you may want to try to wrap the label and combo box to a grid. set the horizontal alignment to stretch for the grid and set the Horizontal alignment to left for the objects.

Setting a min max size is optional but could be useful

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  MinWidth="55" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.636*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalALignment="Left"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks @randyc. Its weird how it loses the plot even with the above definition but with the two items contained within a `StackPanel` with `Oriention` set to `Horizontal`. However, the above definition did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

An `ItemsControl` is not the same as a `ListBox` - It does not contain Selection capabilities.

You're best bet is to use an actual ListBox and modify the ItemTemplate to display the content however you want it.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableValues}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Key}" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" />

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Cheers @Rachel. I spent quite a bit of time even with a `Canvas` setup under a `ItemsPanel`. In the end @randyc's suggestion did the trick.